# Ошибка при выводе информации объекта из массива

Tags: java, массивы

```
Lp 1Name bEtat is 1.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Ewidencja.wydruk(Ewidencja.java:43)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Robotnic rob = new Robotnic("a", 1, 1000, 20, 100);
    Urzednik urz = new Urzednik("b", 1,5000);
    Ewidencja ew = new Ewidencja();
    ew.addPrac(rob);
    ew.addPrac(urz);
    ew.wydruk();
    ew.wydrukRob();
    ew.wydrukUrzed();
    ew.wydrykSeleryForEach();
    ew.ileZatrdPrac();
    ew.sumaSelery();
    ew.delitePracownika("a");
    ew.wydruk();
}

public void wydruk(){
    for (int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++){
        // (43 строчка)     
        System.out.println("Lp " + (i+1) + "Name " + employers[i].getSurname() + "Etat is " + employers[i].getEtat());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас в массив employers лежит null после работника с именем "b". Посмотрите, как он мог туда попасть. И почему в массив не попал работник "а"? Посмотрите всегда ли добавляются в массив работники, и всегда ли по новому индексу, и не добавляется ли лишних в методе addPrac. А вообще массив фиксированного размера, в какой-то момент вам не хватит в нем места, используйте коллекцию какую-нибудь.